# Concatenating an Empty String

Tags: javascript, string-concatenation

While using JavaScript, I am running into problems with concatenating empty strings. For example, declaring

```
var usersToAppend, leadsToAppend = "";
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log(usersToAppend);
    parser = new DOMParser();

    //Get list of users
    var usersXML = parser.parseFromString('<%=WebConnector.getSomeXML()%>', "text/xml");
    console.log(usersXML);
    var users = usersXML.getElementsByTagName("users")[0].childNodes;
    for(var k = 0; k < users.length; k++)
        usersToAppend += users[k].childNodes[0].nodeValue + " -- "+users[k].attributes.getNamedItem("email").nodeValue+"<br>";
});
```

leads to `usersToAppend` beginning with `undefined`. How do I avoid this problem?

**Edit:** I was improperly initializing `usersToAppend` and `leadsToAppend`. Correct initialization code is

```
var usersToAppend = "", var leadsToAppend = "";
```

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) or didn't happen.

Comment: Wait are you initializing `foo` to `""`?

Comment: Yes, because I need to access `foo` in a different function.

Comment: It works fine for me - http://jsfiddle.net/FAR9w/ .

Comment: Your code as posted [will work](http://jsfiddle.net/EXjRS).  If you're *not* initializing `foo` to `""` then the solution to your problem is to do so.  If there's a reason why you can't, please explain.

Comment: @MikeChristensen I posted a simplified version of the code initially. This is the real code I'm having trouble with.

Comment: @JaredNielsen - You need to initialize both: `var usersToAppend = "", leadsToAppend = "";`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to initialize `usersToAppend` to an empty string:

```
var usersToAppend = "", leadsToAppend = "";
```

Empty strings concatenate just fine with other strings. The problem is when you don't assign any value, which is treated as `undefined` and coerces to the string `"undefined"` upon trying to concatenate with another string:

```
var foo = '';
foo += 'baz';
console.log(foo); //"baz"

var bar; //no value, treated as undefined
bar += 'baz';
console.log(bar); //"undefinedbaz", undefined coerced to string is "undefined"
```

Comment: Would it be a better design choice to coerce `undefined` to string as `""`?

Comment: @JanDvorak Do you mean from a ES spec perspective or in the code itself as `foo = (foo || '') + 'baz';`? Well, from a ES spec view, I believe that could lead to some unforeseen bugs which are harder to find. `:P`

Comment: I meant from the ES perspective. It does definitely help bugs stand out - thanks for noting. Concerning the code itself - I do like using default values in Javascript.